# Don't delete record if it has a parent

Tags: delete

I have a `Contract__c` object and a `Auths__c` object.

The `Contract__c` object has a lookup to `Auths__c`, and when a record from `Auths__c` is bound to `Contract__c` I don't want the user to delete the `Auths__c` record. Is that possible? Tia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With custom relationships, such as this field, you can go to the Contract__c object, edit the field that looks up to Auth__c, and set the "What to do if the lookup record is deleted?" section to "Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship."

Answer (score 0):

Solution above does not work.  Using Summer 16 release, the option to change the action when the lookup record is deleted doesn't appear.

Comment: Really?  Still there for me. Be interesting to see a screen shot here and verification that it is a lookup relationship

Comment: As it turns out, there are special considerations when the lookup points to a lead.  In the latest release, there's no control at all - the lookup field will be optional, and the action on delete will be to clear the field.  So to protect a lead from being deleted when it has related records, you must either use master/detail instead of lookup (a problem because the lookup field might not be required), or write a trigger (a problem because, well, *triggers*).

I put an idea (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E3kgQAC) on the SF site to give us back some flexibility.