# Change "what to do if lookup record deleted" for existing field

Tags: lookup

I'm looking at this question [Don't delete record if it has a parent](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60089/dont-delete-record-if-it-has-a-parent) and the answer doesn't work; clicking Edit doesn't make the option to change the behavior available on the screen.  The field is a lookup type, not a master/detail.  If it makes any difference, the field is in a custom object referencing the standard object Lead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the option if it's a Master-Detail field type (it's automatically going to be "delete this record when the parent is deleted"). Instead, you'd have to change the field to a Lookup type, which may not be possible if you have reports, code, or rollup summary fields that depend on the lookup.

Comment: I clarified the question above.  Using Summer 16 release.